# Delphi 10 TMS FireMonkey grid - problem with SelectRows() and RowSelectionCount

Tags: delphi, count, grid, selection, firemonkey

I am using TMS FireMonkey Grid in my app and currently trying to implement the ability to select a range of rows by double-clicking on the first row and then double-clicking on the last row of the range. I use the SelectRows(StartRow,EndRow) method in the OnCellDblClick event handler. It seems to work, except for one thing: the RowSelectionCount does not get set properly (equals 1, regardless how many rows I select) until I call ShowMessage() with something random, like 'Hi!' - after that it gets set to a correct number of selected rows. I figured it has something to do with focus, so I tried to use the SetFocus to change focus to another component of the form and then back to the grid, but that didn't help. Any ideas on how to get RowSelectionCount to carry a correct value right away?
The grid's SelectionMode property is set to smDisjunctRow - according to an email I received from TMS Support, this setting should allow me to use RowSelectionCount.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do TMS say about this?

Comment: The only thing they told me is in order to use RowSelectionCount I need to have SelectionMode set to smDisjunctRow, which I already have. Nothing on the particular issue, although I did explain it to them - twice.

Comment: Update: figured out that this only happens when in the grid properties under Options/Editing the Enabled property is set to False. Once I flip it to True, the functionality is as expected. But I do need to have that property set to False, so currently looking for a workaround.